# Intellij disable SSL verification for git

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I want to disable SSL verification when I import a project into Intellij using git.

I know that in Eclipse you can do that by going to 
`Window->Preferences->Team->Git->Configuration`. Then, you can fill in `https.sslVerify` and `false`.

How can you do this in Intellij?

Comment: In the end I just setup the options from the command line with `git --global`.

Comment: Honestly, that's probably the best way to go about it.  I did poke around IntelliJ, and I didn't find any way to set arbitrary options nor support for this specific issue.

Comment: Bump, UP! Indeed a genuine error.

Answer (score 3):

I have solved the issue by adding

```
set GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=true
```

just before the line

```
"%JAVA_EXE%" %ALL_JVM_ARGS% -cp "%CLASS_PATH%" com.intellij.idea.Main %*
```

in idea.bat (on Windows, the folder is C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1.3\bin )